# Stochstic Gradient Descent for Collaborative Filtering

Tags: gradient-descent, recommender-system

I am currently implementing a model-based Collaborative Filtering approach which relies on the matrix factorization technique. More precisely, I want to factorize the rating matrix `R` to the dot product of `U` and `V`, where both matrices are of low rank. To achieve this, I am currently optimizing a regression loss with Stochastic Gradient Descent: (1) I am randonly selecting an observed instance from R at position `(i,j)`, (2) I compute the gradient regarding the squared difference between the estimated value (implied by the dot product of the i-th row of `U` with the j-th column of `V`) and update the corresponding vectors accordingly.

The first iterations (50 - 100) yield successive progress, however, suddenly the loss increases tremendously (for several steps, until the loss actually overflows). What are possible reasons for this behaviour? Could this be caused by a (too) large value for the learning-rate, since successive steps increasing the loss is, from my understanding, unusual. One interesing observation is, that this does not happen if I choose to update only a single matrix (either `U` or `V`) at a time.